# \AtBeginDocument and \lastskip with polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia

With the following code (minimal working example), \lastskip is 4.31pt.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\AtBeginDocument{\addvspace{1ex}}
\begin{document}
\the\lastskip
\end{document}
```

But if using polyglossia package, \lastskip is 0pt. How can I get the correct \lastskip value in this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the space after polyglossia has added write notes to set language information:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\showoutput
\AfterEndPreamble{\addvspace{1ex}}
\begin{document}
\showlists
\the\lastskip
\end{document}
```

produces a log of

```
### recent contributions:
\write1{\protect \selectlanguage *{latex}}
\write1{\@writefile{toc}{\protect \selectlanguage *{latex}}}
\write1{\@writefile{lof}{\protect \selectlanguage *{latex}}}
\write1{\@writefile{lot}{\protect \selectlanguage *{latex}}}
\glue 4.31
```

with the glue after the write nodes.